# How to delete file API 30

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile

from the last version Android (API 30), the method ".delete()" doesn’t deletes the file because the new  policies doesn’t allow to delete files that are not from the application itself.

I contacted with Google developer support, and I didn't have a valid answer.

My application needs to save an image in an external folder and then delete original image.

```
private fun moveFile(file: File, status: Boolean) {

    var path: String = if (status) {
        absolutePath + File.separator + "Historial imágenes subidas" + File.separator + "Success" + File.separator
    } else {
        absolutePath + File.separator + "Historial imágenes subidas" + File.separator + "Error" + File.separator
    }

    try {

        file.let { sourceFile ->
            val destinationPath = File(path + file.name)
            if (!destinationPath.exists()) {
                sourceFile.copyTo(destinationPath)
                sourceFile.delete()
            } else {
                sourceFile.delete()
            }
        }

    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Toast.makeText(this, e.message.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `file` coming from? Your `moveFile()` function receives it as a parameter, but how are you deriving the value of `file`?

Comment: Are you sure you need to save in external storage? You can save in internal and offer then as media through a ContentProvider

Comment: The files are in the internal memory of the device and I rescue them through an Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE.

The File format is /storage/emulated/0/File Directory/name